# Log Retrieval Script

Tags: bash, ssh

I wrote a simple script to retrieve the logs from my website, and place them in a subdirectory called `logs`. It fetches the logs using sftp. I would like help with the error handling. I'm sure that there are errors I did not see, and I would like to make it so that it fails gracefully.

```
#!/bin/bash
# gets the logs


# Location to place downloaded logs
PlaceLogs=./logs
# ssh connection to sftp files from
SSHLocation=hjsblog
# Location and pattern of logs
GetLogs=../logs/access*


#######################################
#######################################

CWD=$(pwd)

# move to get location
if [ "$(ls -A $PlaceLogs)" ] 
then
    echo $PlaceLogs is not empty
    return
fi
mkdir -p $PlaceLogs
cd $PlaceLogs

# perform the get operation
sftp $SSHLocation << EOF
cd $(dirname $GetLogs)
get $(basename $GetLogs)
EOF

# uncompress files
bunzip2 *.bz2

# return to script dir
cd $CWD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## handle more possibilities

Anything touching the file system can fail.

- **mkdir** You could have permission problems or something else.  Do `mkdir foo || exit 3`.  Feel free to replace the exit with your own function for error handling.
- **cd** is the same deal as `mkdir`
- check for the existance of your directory before `ls`ing it: `if [[ -d $PlaceLogs ]]`

Also, do any `bz2` exist after the `sftp`?  You should check before `bunzip`'ing them.

You can safely ignore all of these things too, but since you specifically asked about error handling it seemed good to point them out.  If this is a critical piece of software then I would build a way for these failures to raise alerts with your DevOps team.

## shellcheck.net

Run all of your scripts through http://www.shellcheck.net/ until you get in better habits.

## use double square brackets

Double square brackets are better than single square brackets.  They have [less surprises](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash).  The primary one is that if you have an empty variable you can do

```
if [[ $FOO == "" ]]
```

where single brackets require a placeholder so none of the arguments disappear if missing:

```
if [ x$FOO == "x" ]
```

Without the `x`s the `$FOO` would disappear as a shell argument when empty.

Comment: Could you state why double square brackets have less surprises or a link to details about that?

Comment: Sure thing.  I had to run an errand so I didn't finish my thought there until now.  Thanks for accepting my answer even then.

Answer (score 1):

#### Suspicious `return`

A `return` statement can only be used in functions or sourced script.
I suspect the posted code is neither.
So I think you want to use `exit` instead.
If not having logs is considered an error/failure,
then you should exit with non-zero, for example `exit 1`.

#### Avoid `cd` within scripts

Whenever possible,
it's good to avoid to change the working directory within scripts.
It's easy to lose track of where you are,
and it's easy to forget to `cd` back to the previous dir,
not to mention additional concerns about error checking of `cd`.

In this example it seems you don't need to `cd` at all.
You could use `sftp` with appropriate source and destination parameters to copy files from and to the right places, for example:

```
sftp $SSHLocation "$remotepath" "$localpath"
```

This way you don't need to `cd` at all, no more need for `CWD=$(pwd)`, and overall fewer concerns.

#### Avoid unnecessary work

It seems that you are using this variable to store two different things:

> ```
> # Location and pattern of logs
> GetLogs=../logs/access*
> ```

Later in the script you split this to parts with:

> ```
> sftp $SSHLocation << EOF
> cd $(dirname $GetLogs)
> get $(basename $GetLogs)
> EOF
> ```

It would have been better to use two variables,
one for the directory name and another for the filename,
so you don't need to split,
and simply use the variables directly.